# List inside component not being listed by json service in Crafter CMS

Tags: content-management-system

have a service call like this `http://localhost:8080/api/1/content_store/item.json?url=/site/components/categories/generic-categories.xml&contextId=24fa1a9c0214657762d111480e594472&=123312321321` xml contains a list of items but json is returning just one  of the items from list configured from authoring form

But if i call with different service with the same xml url like this `http://localhost:8080/studio/api/1/services/api/1/content/get-content.json?site=mysite&path=/site/components/categories/generic-categories.xml&edit=true&ticket=null&nocache=Wed%20Apr%2019%202017%2009:00:16%20GMT-0600%20(CST)&nocache=Wed%20Apr%2019%202017%2009:00:16%20GMT-0600%20(CST)`
it returns the list of items

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two services mentioned in the question are two different services of two different Crafter applications (Engine and Studio). The first service call belongs to Engine and the second belongs to Studio. By urls i assume Engine is configured as preview for Studio.
Aside that these services belong to different applications, expected response of two services is different. Studio's expected response is content of specified xml file from Studio's content repository. Engine's expected response is item content from (preview) content store, where item represents xml after applied merge strategies. In general use case Studio content repository and Engine content store are two different locations and can be out of sync.
To get these services to respond with same or comparable response:

- Synchronize Studio content repository and Engine (preview) content store
- make sure Engine cache is configure properly (or clear Engine's cache)
- clear browser cache